# Linux find file in folder and move it to new location with time prefix

Tags: find, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I have a backup folder that is  accessible with sftp. The Idea is that backup coming to this folder but should not stay there. I want to move them with a cron job. This is already possible but because I can't be sure that a filename is unique I would like to prefix the file while moving it.

```
* * * * * find /src/backup/ -mmin +60 -exec mv "{}" /dest/backup/ \;
```

How can I modify the command in such a way that ether the file itself gets a prefix
e.g. `yyyymmdd-MMSS-` or that a new folder is used e.g. `yyyymmdd`?

Comment: Is the time stamp the from the move time or the file's modification time?

Comment: Preferable the file's modification time, but if this is not possible the move time would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So because I need some flexibility any way I came up with a script version based on the idea from AFH.

```
#!/bin/sh

# configure: source path
source_path="/src/path/backup";

# configure: destination path
destination_path="/dest/path/backup";

# find all files in source_path not modified in the last 60 minutes
find $source_path -mmin +60 -type f | while read -r file; do

    # this is the absolute source path (/src/path/backup/path/to/file)
    absolute_source_path="${file%/*}";

    # get the relative source path (/path/to/file)
    relative_source_path=${absolute_source_path#$source_path}

    # get the last modification date of the file (yyyymmdd)
    file_save_date="$(date -d@$(stat "$file" -c %Y) +'%Y%m%d')";

    # IMPORTANT create sub directory at the destination if required
    mkdir --parents "$destination_path/$file_save_date$relative_source_path/";

    # move the file to new destination (/dest/path/backup/yyyymmdd/path/to/file)
    mv "$file" "$destination_path/$file_save_date$relative_source_path/" > /dev/null 2>&1;

done

# delete empty folders if the the folder is not changes in the last 5 minutes
find $source_path/* -mmin +5 -type d -empty -delete > /dev/null 2>&1;
```

Comment: You don't need `sed` to strip the source path: you can equally use parameter expansion, which avoids the overhead of running an external program: `relative_source_path=${absolute_source_path#$source_path}`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need scripting to do this, so you cannot do this with the `-exec` option directly (unless you use `bash -c`, which makes quoting and parameter expansion difficult).

There are two options:-

- Use `find /src/backup/ | while read -r f; do ...; done` - this will work if you have normal file names (no leading/trailing spaces, nor embedded new-lines).
- Call a script file which has the commands you need, eg `find /src/backup/ -mmin +60 -exec /Path/To/moveunique {} /dest/backup/` - in this case I recommend putting the full script path into the `crontab` line, as its environment is different from your interactive shell.

I'll illustrate the first option: it should be obvious how to use similar commands in a script file:

```
find /src/backup/ | while read -r f; do \
    mv "$f" /dest/backup/"${f%/*}"/$(date -d@$(stat "$f" -c %Y) +'%Y%m%d-%H%M')-"${f##*/}"; \
done
```

This uses `stat` to get the file's modification time, `date` to format the time fields you want, and parameter expansion to separate the file's directory path and name.

This makes a rather long command string (I used continuation lines to make it more readable, and I haven't checked if `crontab` supports this), so you prefer to use a script.

Comment: The absolute folder is what you had in your original `mv` command, and I don't recommend using a relative path in a `crontab` command, for the reason I gave above. You may also wish to omit the source directory from the target folder, if you want all the back-up files in a single directory.

Comment: If you use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`, a relative path will be relative to each source file's path: is this what you want?

Comment: Alternatively, use `cd /src/backup/; find . {Options} ...; cd "$OLDPWD"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no option in `mv` equivalent to `mkdir -p`, but it's easy enough to incorporate the latter command when you're using a script, which you have wisely chosen as the preferred solution.